# What's the alternative to JavaSupport when using C# to read "Java" db4o databases?

Tags: c#, java, deprecated, db4o

I'm working with a db4o database that was created in Java, but I'm using C#.

The code I'm using is based on [an example from the Versant site](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.12/net2/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/aliases/cross-platform_aliasing.html)

However, the **Db4objects.Db4o.Config.JavaSupport** class used in the example is marked as obsolete in the latest (since 8.0) versions of the db4o assemblies.

Is there a new approach when reading Java objects from a db4o database using C#? If so, can someone point me to some sample code for the new approach? I couldn't find anything when searching.

Comment: One of the top google links for "db4o .net provider": http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25669/An-introduction-to-LINQ-for-db4o

Comment: I think I have to do some alias mapping to read Java objects into .NET objects, don't I? If that's no longer required for some reason, then I'm missing something - as I get a conversion error when I don't do that initial mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works, but maybe worth a try: Use IKVM.NET to run the JAVA version of db4o together with the original Java classes. That way you don't need to rely on the not supported 'JavaSupport'-stuff in db4o.

I haven't tried it, but I can imagine that it work. I already used IKVM.NET to run other non trivial Java libraries within .NET.